# WSO2 APIM and BAM - How do I resolve null value issue?

Tags: configuration, wso2

I am using WSO2 API Manager 1.6.0 and BAM 2.4.0.

When attempting to gather stats I get this error in BAM:

```
TID: [0] [BAM] [2014-02-13 10:46:17,841] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.db.DBOperation} -  Failed to write data to database {org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.db.DBOperation}
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'consumerKey', table 'wso2_regdb.dbo.API_REQUEST_SUMMARY'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:671)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.processResults(JtdsStatement.java:613)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQL(JtdsStatement.java:572)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:727)
        at org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.db.DBOperation.insertData(DBOperation.java:175)
        at org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.db.DBOperation.writeToDB(DBOperation.java:63)
        at org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.db.DBRecordWriter.write(DBRecordWriter.java:35)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.processOp(FileSinkOperator.java:589)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:471)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:762)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:84)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:471)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:762)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:84)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:471)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:762)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.forward(GroupByOperator.java:964)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.closeOp(GroupByOperator.java:1016)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:557)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecReducer.close(ExecReducer.java:304)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:528)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:419)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:257)
```

I realize I could simply allow consumerkey to allow null values...but updating the DDL defined by WSo2 seems like a bad idea.

I think this may be related to an issue that the API Manager has when attempting to use the 'tryit' feature and the key is not properly received.  I would get an error of:

```
TID: [0] [AM] [2014-02-13 14:25:02,513] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler} -  API authentication failure {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler}
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APISecurityException: Access failure for API: /APIPhoneVerify, version: 2.0.0 with key: null
```

I've posted the 'tryit' issue before and was told to update my config based on: http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Adding+Documentation+Using+Swagger which I did, but it didn't help.

Any ideas on how to clear this error for BAM?  AND/OR fix the 'tryit' feature?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the NULL value insertion happens when trying to access the API with try it feature. This will send a pre-flight OPTION request to see if the browser is allowed to access the resource and this request doesn't send the Access Token along with it. Since it is through the access token, the consumer key is derived, when the OPTIONS request goes through the gateway, it won't be possible to find a consumer key associated with it - so a null value will be pushed to BAM. This seems to be a bug and you can report this problem at https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER.

However, the NULL value insertion doesn't have any impact on invoking the API. According to the error provided, the request sent from tryit(the actual request, not the pre-flight one) doesn't seem to be sending the Access Token.

Comment: So there is not a way to clear the record so that BAM will stop trying to process it.  It attempts to do so over and over.

Comment: These values are kept in a cassandra column family named  org_wso2_apimgt_statistics_request. Currently there's no way to modify a column family through BAM interface. Alternatively,you can use cqlsh provided with Apache Cassandra, connect to the embedded cassandra storage of the BAM and delete all the null values from the org_wso2_apimgt_statistics_request column family. After that you might have to delete all the meta data tables created by the hive script as mentioned in http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics (Changing database section)